# Cannot view xps file inside iFrame. If iFrame is expanded than file shows up

Tags: pdf, xps

This only happens on windows XP and works fine on Windows 7.

In our application we display many different file types. One them is xps. If iFrame window is big enough it displays fine but I make it smaller than I get the followin error:

Event Type: Error

Event Source: Application Error

Event Category: None

Event ID: 1000

Date: 10/13/2010

Time: 10:47:13 AM

User: N/A

Computer: CS-XP-IE8

Description:

Faulting application xpsviewer.exe, version 3.0.6920.1427, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.5781, fault address 0x00012afb.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Data:

0000: 41 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74   Applicat

0008: 69 6f 6e 20 46 61 69 6c   ion Fail

0010: 75 72 65 20 20 78 70 73   ure  xps

0018: 76 69 65 77 65 72 2e 65   viewer.e

0020: 78 65 20 33 2e 30 2e 36   xe 3.0.6

0028: 39 32 30 2e 31 34 32 37   920.1427

0030: 20 69 6e 20 6b 65 72 6e    in kern

0038: 65 6c 33 32 2e 64 6c 6c   el32.dll

0040: 20 35 2e 31 2e 32 36 30    5.1.260

0048: 30 2e 35 37 38 31 20 61   0.5781 a

0050: 74 20 6f 66 66 73 65 74   t offset

0058: 20 30 30 30 31 32 61 66    00012af

0060: 62 0d 0a                  b..

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update to .NET 3.5 SP2 or download hotfix for xpsviewer